# Setting the page title from a usercontrol in Umbraco

Tags: c#, user-controls, umbraco, page-lifecycle

I am having this problem on a site built with **Umbraco v3.0.3**.

The master page is, as far as I know, stored by the CMS in the database. Thus when I do the following in my master page, it's not being processed and in fact the head isn't runat server. So the following comes through to the page in the browser:

```
<head runat="server">
```

Consequently, I'm having problems using the following from within my usercontrol

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Page.Title = "Lorem Ipsum";
}
```

Which gives the following server error

> Using the Title property of Page requires a header control on the page. (e.g. runat="server" />)

I just want a simple and clean way of setting the page title from a usercontrol!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you also embellish the title tag with runat="server"
like

```
<head runat="server">
<title runat="server"></title>
</head>
```

Off the tangent, why would you need to set the page title from a user control? You would be better of having a page item or umbraco macro(possibly an asp.net user control) sitting inside the `<title></title>` tag that sets the page title for you.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but it doesn't make a difference. I could write any server-side code in there and it wouldn't process it. As I mentioned, the runat="server" just comes through to the page markup.

Comment: There is a umbraco macro asp.net usercontrol which loads data from an API. I get information from this call and display it on the page (product details), along with the product name, which I need to put in the title tag for SEO purposes.

Comment: Did you try using the <?ASPNET_HEAD>...</?ASPNET_HEAD> element? I believe that's the template markup used in umbraco v3 to denote a server side head element. If this doesn't work I'd suggest adding a new user control to the title, which repeats the call to the API. If it's an expensive call, you could always cache the value in the Session.